# Different hostings site online

Tags: dns, cname

I have a domain at godaddy, I have a hosting at an other one.

How can I set the domainname to the hosting?

I guess CNAME and IP needs to be used?
Do I need to set MX settings? 
Is CNAME the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create an A record for the other hosting site's IP address that they gave you, and put the A record into godaddy's records.  Once you do that, any lookups will cause a web browser (say) to go to the hosting site instead.  You shouldn't need a CNAME at all.

Note that all DNS records have a TTL value that means it'll take a bit for it to switch.  So once you add the A record, don't expect it to work right away because godaddy's fake "under construction" type parked page will still be there until the TTL expires.

You only need MX settings if you want mail delivery, which your hosting provider may or may not give you.  If they do, then yes you'll want an MX record to point to it if you're going to make use of mail.

Comment: I'd like to use the hostings email, not GoDaddy's.
So how do I do that? With the NS? or do I need to set MX, if so how?

Comment: you do it with an MX entry, where the MX name you put on the name line is the same as your web server (or you might need to create another A record if the IP address of their mail server is different).